# how to make generic method having List<dto> paramter for method c#

Tags: c#

Need to create generic method which will accept `List<child1>` and `List<child2>`.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductRate { get; set; }
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{

}

public class Child2 : Parent
{

}
```

**Program : As shown below i am trying to to pass the values in method**

```
public class HelloFriend
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Child1> child1 = new List<Child1>()
        {
            new Child1(){ Name="Admin", ProductRate = 10}
        };

        List<Child2> child2 = new List<Child2>()
        {
            new Child2(){ Name="Admin", ProductRate = 50}
        };

        decimal result1 =  getvalues(child1, 10);
        decimal result2 =  getvalues(child2, 10);
    }

    public static decimal getvalues(List<Child1> list, decimal calculateValue)
    {
        decimal value = 1;

        if(parentList !=null )
        {
            foreach( var item in parentList)
            {
                value = item.ProductRate * 100 * calculateValue;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

How to make getvalues() generics that will work with all List of Child1 and Chil2

Comment: Why not use a List<Parent>?

Comment: its demo code but having 3 diff. sql to fetch the data , keeping separate code

Comment: You're only enumerating the list (not modifying it) so you should be able to change the parameter's type to `IEnumerable<Parent>` and still pass it your `List<Child1>` and `List<Child2>`. If you really need to work with a list in the get values function, you can change to a `List<Parent>` but you'd also have to make your lists in Main be of that type as well (and *not* `List<Child1>`) as there is no inheritence relation between `List<Base>` and `List<Derived>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short console project to illustrate the use of generic types here:
[I used the object definitions of your question]

```
static void Main()
{
    List<Child1> child1s = new List<Child1>()
    {
        new Child1() { Name="c11", ProductRate=1},
        new Child1() { Name="c12", ProductRate=2}
    };

    List<Child2> child2s = new List<Child2>()
    {
        new Child2() { Name="c21", ProductRate=30},
        new Child2() { Name="c21", ProductRate=60}
    };

    foreach (var retval in GetValues(child1s, 5))
        System.Console.WriteLine(retval);
    foreach (var retval in GetValues(child2s, 5))
        System.Console.WriteLine(retval);

    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
public static IEnumerable<decimal> GetValues<T>(List<T> items, decimal calculatedValue) where T : Parent
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        yield return (decimal)(item.ProductRate * 100 * calculatedValue);
    }
}
```

The function is defined as `List<T>` where `T` is the generic type parameter. This parameter is further limited by `where T : Parent` to fit only on objects of type `Parent` or inherited types of it.

You can also get the type of the given instance by `typeof(T)` to differentiate if needed, but for this kind you should first read further into generics.

Another way is as in KYL3Rs answer described, to define the input parameter as `IEnumerable<Parent>`(in his answer `List<Parent>`). That way you need no generics, just inheritance and implicit casting. You need `IEnumerable<T>` here, otherwise a conversation isn't implicit and must be made by hand.

```
static void Main()    
{
    .....
    foreach (var retval in GetValues(child1s, 5))
        System.Console.WriteLine(retval);
    foreach (var retval in GetValues(child2s, 5))
        System.Console.WriteLine(retval);

    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
public static IEnumerable<decimal> GetValues(IEnumerable<Parent> items, decimal calculatedValue)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        yield return (decimal)(item.ProductRate * 100 * calculatedValue);
    }
}
```

Please also note my return value of a list of items (`IEnumerable<decimal>`) and the `yield return` statement. I think your single return value after processing a list was a bug. And I use `IEnumerable` to make it clear I do not modify the given collection.

Answer (score 1):

Basic knowledge about inheritance: use a list of `Parent` and **declare** the getters/setters you need in `Parent` (like you did).

```
public static decimal getvalues(List<Parent> list, decimal calculateValue)
{

}
```

As the comments said, usage: (use Parent as list type)

```
List<Parent> child1 = new List<Parent>()
{
    new Child1(){ Name="Admin", ProductRate = 10}
};
decimal result1 =  getvalues(child1, 10);
```

Alternative: (cast the child-list)

```
List<Child1> child1 = new List<Child1>()
{
    new Child1(){ Name="Admin", ProductRate = 10}
};
decimal result1 =  getvalues(child1.Cast<Parent>(), 10);
```

Comment: getting error like this cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TheConsole.Child>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TheConsole.Parent>'

Comment: Tiger's right here. The relation List<Child> and List<Parent> is not the same as Child and Parent. In this case you'd need to cast explicitly by myChildList.Cast<Parent>() before passing it to the function.